# Creating folder in file-explorer using DDMS perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, directory, ddms

I am trying to create a new folder for sd-card using DDMS perspective.

Few days ago I created a sub-folder named `DCIM` in folder called `sdcard`:

**Snapshot-1:**
[image]

**Problem I am facing:**

- Today I can't access that folder
- If I try to create the folder again I get an error as below but as stated I can't see the folder also created few days ago

[image]

**How to resolve this ?**

Answer (score 1):

By default sdcard folder contains a folder named `DCIM`. Thats why you are getting that message. Try creating a folder with some other name.