# "File Exists" error when creating new folder in the DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

i'm trying to create a new folder in the DDMS perspective.

i'm trying to create a ringtones folder under mnt\sdcard but i keep getting the following error:

[image: DDMS ERROR]

there was a similar question ([Creating folder in file-explorer using DDMS perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045087/creating-folder-in-file-explorer-using-ddms-perspective)) but the answer there is unclear.

for some reason i can't see the folder I've created.

restarting the eclipse and emulator didn't help.

any ideas ?

thx

Comment: Do you use Emulator or device?

Comment: i'm using an emulator

Comment: This file is exist. I think you need to remove it then create again. Can you create another folder name?

Answer (score 0):

You must add some SD card size in your emulator:
[image]